# How to exclude the array from the array for nested condition

Tags: javascript

Given the array, how do I filter out the array matching layer.id?

```
nodes = [
    {id: '1', layer: {id: 'a'}},
    {id: '4', layer: {id: 'b'}},
    {id: '2'},
    {id: '3'},
]

argument = 'a'

// OUTPUT
[
    {id: '4', layer: {id: 'b'}},
    {id: '2'},
    {id: '3'},
]
```

This statement somehow clear out 2 and 3 elements from the array because I'm checking the node.layer field.

```
nodes.filter(node => node.layer && node.layer.id !== id) // TO-DO: How do I flip..?
    .map(node => node.id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invert the test for `node.layer` and use `||` instead of `&&`.

```js
const nodes = [
    {id: '1', layer: {id: 'a'}},
    {id: '4', layer: {id: 'b'}},
    {id: '2'},
    {id: '3'},
];

argument = 'a';
const result = nodes.filter(node => !node.layer || node.layer.id != argument).map(({id}) => id);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61374256/how-to-filter-two-fields-from-nested-array-in-javascript

Comment: ^I have a similar challenge.. I really should practice JS

Answer (score 1):

You've already accurately described why your first approach doesn't work. To overcome the problem, step back and realise that you need to keep those elements which either have no layer or have a layer with the same `id` from the one specified.

This leads to:

1
Given the array, how do I filter out the array matching layer.id?

```js
nodes = [
    {id: '1', layer: {id: 'a'}},
    {id: '4', layer: {id: 'b'}},
    {id: '2'},
    {id: '3'},
]

argument = 'a'

console.log(nodes.filter(node => !node.layer || node.layer.id !== argument))
```

(I've left out your use of `.map` because then the output doesn't match what you showed as desired - but you can put that in too if you prefer.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61374256/how-to-filter-two-fields-from-nested-array-in-javascript < You can try this too

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to add one more condition to the `.filter` method, like this:

```
var output = nodes.filter(n => {
  if ('layer' in n) {
    return n.layer.id !== argument;
  }
  return n;
});
```

The `return n;` will return the 2 and 3 elements in case `layer` prop doesn't exist.