# how to filter two fields from nested array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Given edges, I would like exclude any edge which have both nodes points.

```
nodes = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

edges = [
    {id: 'a', src: '1', target: '2'}, <<exclude cuz '1', '2' are in nodes
    {id: 'b', src: '4', target: '3'}, <<exclude
    {id: 'c', src: '1', target: '5'}, <<DO NOT exclude cuz only '1' is in nodes
    {id: 'd', src: '6', target: '2'}, <<DO NOT
    {id: 'e', src: '6', target: '8'}, <<DO NOT
]

output = ['c', 'd', 'e']
```

Can you complete the below statement..?? Or do you have any efficient solution?

```js
nodes = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

edges = [
    {id: 'a', src: '1', target: '2'}, //exclude cuz '1', '2' are in nodes
    {id: 'b', src: '4', target: '3'}, //exclude
    {id: 'c', src: '1', target: '5'}, //DO NOT exclude cuz only '1' is in nodes
    {id: 'd', src: '6', target: '2'}, //DO NOT
    {id: 'e', src: '6', target: '8'}, //DO NOT
]

console.log(edges.filter({src, target} => nodes.includes(src) && nodes.includes(target)).map({id}=>id));
```

Comment: If I've understood your intentions correctly, all you need to do is wrap the `nodes.includes(src) && nodes.includes(target)` in parentheses and use the `!` operator, since this describes exactly the condition you want to *exclude*.

Comment: Do we have any more efficient algorithm?

Comment: Fix the syntax errors in your arrow functions and after then do the opposite in your filter since you are picking out the elements that match.

Comment: When you use a destructuring argument list in an arrow function, you have to put `()` around it.

Comment: Sort the nodes array and binary search instead of using [].includes to achieve O(N log N)

Comment: Or as Barmar answered, convert array nodes into a Set, then you will achieve a constant check-time nearly 1, then O(N)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just invert the test with `!` to remove elements instead of keeping them when they match the criteria.

And I've fixed the syntax of your destructuring argument lists.

```js
nodes = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

edges = [
    {id: 'a', src: '1', target: '2'}, //exclude cuz '1', '2' are in nodes
    {id: 'b', src: '4', target: '3'}, //exclude
    {id: 'c', src: '1', target: '5'}, //DO NOT exclude cuz only '1' is in nodes
    {id: 'd', src: '6', target: '2'}, //DO NOT
    {id: 'e', src: '6', target: '8'}, //DO NOT
]

console.log(edges.filter(({src, target}) => !(nodes.includes(src) && nodes.includes(target))).map(({id})=>id));
```

If `nodes` is large, you can improve efficiency significantly by changing it to a `Set` instead of an array.

Comment: Thanks Barmar!  Follow up problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61400327/how-to-filter-nested-array-and-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

When you destructure you need to have parenthesis around it. And your check is doing the opposite of you want in the filter. So invert the boolean.

```js
nodes = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

edges = [
    {id: 'a', src: '1', target: '2'}, // <<exclude cuz '1', '2' are in nodes
    {id: 'b', src: '4', target: '3'}, // <<exclude
    {id: 'c', src: '1', target: '5'}, // <<DO NOT exclude cuz only '1' is in nodes
    {id: 'd', src: '6', target: '2'}, // <<DO NOT
    {id: 'e', src: '6', target: '8'}, // <<DO NOT
]


var result = edges.filter(({
  src,
  target
}) => !(nodes.includes(src) && nodes.includes(target))).map(({
  id
}) => id);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a more efficient approach with a short circuit if a node is not found.

```js
var nodes = ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    nodesSet = new Set(nodes),
    edges = [{ id: 'a', src: '1', target: '2' }, { id: 'b', src: '4', target: '3' }, { id: 'c', src: '1', target: '5' }, { id: 'd', src: '6', target: '2' }, { id: 'e', src: '6', target: '8' }],
    result = edges
        .filter(({ src, target }) => !nodesSet.has(src) || !nodesSet.has(target))
        .map(({ id }) => id)

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite efficient and is nearly correct. Here is how it should be correct:

1. When making arrow functions, parenthesis are always required around the argument list **except** when your function has 1 simple argument. You are using destructuring arguments and they always require parenthesis.
2. Your function for the filter should return `true` when you want to maintain the element in the resulting array. As it is, you have the opposite.

So the following should work for you:

```
edges.filter(({src, target}) => !nodes.includes(src) || !nodes.includes(target)).map(({id})=>id)
```